# ES6 versus CommonJS in webpacker-based Rails/Tailwind project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker, tailwind-css

I've set up a new Rails application with Webpacker and added Tailwind and Stimulus as dependencies.

When I create a Stimulus controller with the default generator it seems to use .es6:

All the examples of javascript in the app/javascript/packs seem to also use .es6:

```
import "stylesheets/application";

import Rails from "rails-ujs";
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks";

Rails.start();
Turbolinks.start();

import "controllers";
```

However, the webpacker environment files, tailwind.config.js, et al seem to use CommonJS:

```
// tailwind.config.js

// FIXME: why no es6 here when it's elsewhere?
const { colors } = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

module.exports = {
  theme: {},
  variants: {},
  plugins: []
}
```

and

```
// config/webpack/production.js

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'

const environment = require('./environment')

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

I'm looking for an explanation of why the two flavors. Can I (and should I) standardize on one or the other?

Somewhat related question: if I switch all my assets over to webpacker, is it save to just delete the app/assets folder completely or is there an "uninstall" process for that I should follow (remove gems, etc.)?

Comment: You'll find different module patterns in Javascript ecosystem. Some libraries will use NodeJS modules, some will use UMDs, some will use ES6 modules. Reasons vary as to why it is like this. Slow adoption of better module patterns, unfinished specs, interoperability issues with the existing codebases, etc.